# Determine the correct radio button value with php

Tags: php

So I have the following form with **radio buttons**.

1. how can I get their values on submit with PHP?
2. When I choose male it should print a message `success` else it will print `fail`
3. Also when you don't choose something it should show please choose something

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try `$_GET['gender']`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isset php API. Guide at this [link to the php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    { 
        if(isset($_POST["gender"]))
        {
            $gender = $_POST["gender"];
            if($gender == "male")
            {
               echo "success";
            }
            else
            {
               echo "failed";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Please choose something";
        }
     }
?>
```

**Output** :- When choose male it should print a message ***success*** else it will print ***failed*** , Also when you don't choose something it should show ***Please choose something***